# when changing routes, the data in my datasource keeps adding to the existing table datasource; Angular 7 material design issue

Tags: angular, datasource

The data in my material table is changing when I change the route. for example if I change the route and go back to the table route, the existing data is doubled.

So I want to show some data in my Angular app that has been pulled from my firebase database. Currently the data is in the form of an Observable.

I've made a new class that extends the DataSource class from the RxJS library. this class has a connect method where I return my data as an observable.

```
import { User } from './../models/user.model';
import { FirestoreService } from './../services/firestore.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core' 
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-klantenoverzicht',
  templateUrl: './klantenoverzicht.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./klantenoverzicht.component.css']
})
export class KlantenoverzichtComponent implements OnInit {

  users: UserDataSource;
  displayedCols: string[] = ["uid", "naam", "adres", "telefoonnummer", "isKlant"];

  constructor(private db: FirestoreService, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.db.getUsers()
    //     .subscribe(users => {
    //       this.users = new MatTableDataSource(users);
    //       this.users.data = users;
    //       this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    //       console.log(this.users)
    //     });
    this.users = new UserDataSource(this.db);
    // this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}

export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any>{

  constructor(private db: FirestoreService){
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<User[]>{
    return this.db.getUsers();
  }

  disconnect(){}
}
```

Above is the component that generates the table data.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="users">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="uid">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> GebruikersID </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.uid}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="naam">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Naam </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.naam}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="adres">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Adres </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.adres}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="telefoonnummer">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Telefoonnummer </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.telefoonnummer}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="isKlant">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Rol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> Klant </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedCols"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedCols; let entry" [ngClass]="{ 'hide' : entry.isKlant == false}" ></tr>
</table>
```

The actual result is when change routes back and forth, the rows in the table keep adding up with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Not to sure what your UserDataSource is, but i think its whats causing you the issue. The MatTableDataSource function should only take a simple array. I'm assuming your subscribe response is returning an array of user's, which should simply be passed into the MatTableDataSource and then used in your frontend html code [dataSource]="dataSource".

I also noticed you are trying to use some change detection, I'd suggest looking into a BehaviorSubject for data manipulation in your table.

```
public dataSource: MatTableDataSource;

ngOnInIt() {
  this.getUsers();
}

private getUser(): void {
  this.db.getUsers()
    .subscribe(
      res => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res),
      err => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

Comment: the UserDataSource is a class defined at the bottom of the component. I read somewhere that you have to extend the common interface DataSource, so that you can override the connect() and disconnect() methods. I have tried what you suggested and the problem with that solution is that the datasource becomes null after I change the routes.

Comment: Are your routes sharing the same component? If they are is there any thing that would overwrite/share the dataSource object by chance? Might be easier to debug as well if you are able to get your code into a plunker for other people to see as well, if you have the option of doing so.

Comment: That won't be necessary, I solved the problem. the problem lied in the fact that observable was of the type snapshot instead of valuechanges. I don't know why this was the problem because I converted the snapshot observable into a proper datatype and it was displaying correctly in the table. But thanks anyway for the effort.